# If statement in a for loop VHDL

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, vhdl, min, quartus

I want to do a for loop for 8 inputs and an if statement.My purpose is to find minimum of these 8 portsI know what the error is but i want to make (Ι-1) when the (i) take the value of 7.Any ideas?
if (a_unss(i)

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164 .all;
USe ieee.numeric_std .all;
---------------------------------------

ENTITY bitmin IS
generic
(     
size: integer            :=8

);
PORT
(
        A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7 : IN UNSIGNED (size-1 downto 0);

        MinOut:out  UNSIGNED (size-1 downto 0)
);     
END Entity;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------


ARCHITECTURE compare OF bitmin IS

type a_uns is array (0 to 7) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal a_unss:a_uns;



begin
        a_unss(0)<=(A0);
        a_unss(1)<=(A1);
        a_unss(2)<=(A2);
        a_unss(3)<=(A3);
        a_unss(4)<=(A4);
        a_unss(5)<=(A5);
        a_unss(6)<=(A6);
        a_unss(7)<=(A7);

process(a_unss) 


begin
MinOut<="00000000";
for i in 0 to 7 loop



              if (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1))and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1))and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) then
                     MinOut<=a_unss(i);


        end if;
    end loop;
end process;
END compare;
```

Error:
Error (10385): VHDL error at bitmin.vhd(48): index value 8 is outside the range (0 to 7) of object "a_unss"

Error (10658): VHDL Operator error at bitmin.vhd(48): failed to evaluate call to operator ""<""
Error (10658): VHDL Operator error at bitmin.vhd(48): failed to evaluate call to operator ""and""
Error (12153): Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy
Error: Quartus Prime Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 4 errors, 1 warning
Error: Peak virtual memory: 4826 megabytes
Error: Processing ended: Thu Apr 09 19:39:04 2020
Error: Elapsed time: 0`enter code here`0:00:17
Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:43

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names "An indexed name denotes an element of an array. ... The prefix of an indexed name shall be appropriate for an array type. The expressions specify the index values for the element; there shall be one such expression for each index position of the array, and each expression shall be of the type of the corresponding index. For the evaluation of an indexed name, the prefix and the expressions are evaluated. It is an error if an index value does not belong to the range of the corresponding index range of the array."

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the for-loop index goes out of range of the array length. You also need to produce a chain of minimums. And the bit width within the Compare architecture should be dependent upon the generic SIZE.

In Version 1 below, a single long chain is used.

In Version 2 below, two half-length chains are used which gives a shorter overall propagation delay.

In Version 3 below, a tree structure is used which gives the shortest overall propagation delay.

## Version 1 - One long chain

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity BitMin is
    generic
    (
        SIZE: integer := 8
    );
    port
    (
        a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7: in unsigned(SIZE - 1 downto 0);

        minout: out unsigned(SIZE - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture Compare of BitMin is

    subtype TBits is unsigned(SIZE - 1 downto 0);  -- Changed TByte to TBits because the bit width is dependent upon the generic SIZE.

    type TBitsArray is array(0 to 7) of TBits;

    signal inputs: TBitsArray;
    signal min_chain: TBitsArray;

    function Minimum(a, b: TBits) return TBits is
    begin
        if a < b then
            return a;
        end if;
        return b;
    end function;

begin
    inputs <= ( a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7 );

    -- Version 1 (one long chain)
    process(inputs, min_chain)
    begin
        min_chain(0) <= inputs(0);  -- Assume the first element in the array is the minimum.

        for i in 1 to 7 loop  -- Cycle through the remaining items to find the minimum.
            min_chain(i) <= Minimum(min_chain(i - 1), inputs(i));
        end loop;
        minout <= min_chain(7);
    end process;

end Compare;
```

## Version 2 - Two half-length chains

```vhdl
    -- Version 2 (two half-length chains: 0..3 and 7..4)
    process(inputs, min_chain)
    begin
        min_chain(0) <= inputs(0);  -- Assume the first element in the array is the minimum.
        min_chain(7) <= inputs(7);  -- Assume the last element in the array is the minimum.

        for i in 1 to 3 loop  -- Cycle through the remaining items to find the minimum.
            min_chain(i) <= Minimum(min_chain(i - 1), inputs(i));  -- Work forwards from element 1.
            min_chain(7 - i) <= Minimum(min_chain(7 - i + 1), inputs(7 - i));  -- Work backwards from element 6.
        end loop;
        minout <= Minimum(min_chain(3), min_chain(4));  -- Find the minimum of the two chains.
    end process;
```

## Version 3 - Tree

[image: Tree]

```vhdl
    -- Version 3 (tree structure)
    process(inputs)
        constant NUM_INPUTS: natural := inputs'length;
        constant NUM_STAGES: natural := natural(ceil(log2(real(NUM_INPUTS))));
        type TTree is array(0 to NUM_STAGES) of TBitsArray;  -- This declares a matrix, but we only use half of it (a triangle shape). The unused part will not be synthesized.
        variable min_tree: TTree;
        variable height: natural;
        variable height_int: natural;
        variable height_rem: natural;
        variable a, b: TBits;
    begin
        -- Stage 0 is simply the inputs
        min_tree(0) := inputs;
        height := NUM_INPUTS;

        for i in 1 to NUM_STAGES loop

            -- Succeeding stages are half the height of the preceding stage.
            height_int := height / 2;
            height_rem := height rem 2;  -- Remember the odd one out.

            -- Process pairs in the preceding stage and assign the result to the succeeding stage.
            for j in 0 to height_int - 1 loop
                a := min_tree(i - 1)(j);
                b := min_tree(i - 1)(j + height_int);
                min_tree(i)(j) := Minimum(a, b);
            end loop;

            -- Copy the odd one out in the preceding stage to the succeeding stage
            if height_rem = 1 then
                a := min_tree(i - 1)(height - 1);
                min_tree(i)(height_int) := a;
            end if;

            -- Adjust the ever-decreasing height for the succeeding stage.
            height := height_int + height_rem;
        end loop;

        -- Get the value at the point of the triangle which is the minimum of all inputs.
        minout <= min_tree(NUM_STAGES)(0);
    end process;
```

## Test Bench

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity BitMin_TB is
end entity;

architecture V1 of BitMin_TB is

    constant SIZE_TB: natural := 8;

    component BitMin is
        generic
        (
            SIZE: integer := 8
        );
        port
        (
            a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7: in unsigned (SIZE - 1 downto 0);

            minout: out unsigned (SIZE - 1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    signal a0_tb, a1_tb, a2_tb, a3_tb, a4_tb, a5_tb, a6_tb, a7_tb: unsigned(SIZE_TB - 1 downto 0);

    signal minout_tb: unsigned(SIZE_TB - 1 downto 0);

begin

    DUT: BitMin
        generic map
        (
            SIZE => SIZE_TB
        )
        port map
        (
            a0 => a0_tb,
            a1 => a1_tb,
            a2 => a2_tb,
            a3 => a3_tb,
            a4 => a4_tb,
            a5 => a5_tb,
            a6 => a6_tb,
            a7 => a7_tb,

            minout => minout_tb
        );

    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        a0_tb <= "00000100";
        a1_tb <= "00001000";
        a2_tb <= "00010000";
        a3_tb <= "00100000";
        a4_tb <= "01000000";
        a5_tb <= "10000000";
        a6_tb <= "00000010";
        a7_tb <= "00000001";
        wait for 10 ns;
        --std.env.stop;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

## Synthesis Comparison

All three versions synthesise to the same amount of logic elements, but Version 3 is the fastest.

### Version 1 RTL - one long chain

[image]

### Version 2 RTL - two half-length chains

[image]

### Version 3 RTL - tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```vhdl
if (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1))and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1))and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) then
```

The indexing of `a_unss(i+1)` is causing a problem as you are iterating form 0 to 7. When `i` reaches 7, `i+1` is equal to 8 which is greater than the boundaries of `a_unss`. This is what the message : `Error (10385): VHDL error at bitmin.vhd(48): index value 8 is outside the range (0 to 7) of object "a_unss"` is saying.

**EDIT**

Suggestion to update the code:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164 .all;
USe ieee.numeric_std .all;
---------------------------------------

ENTITY bitmin IS
generic
(     
size: integer            :=8

);
PORT
(
        A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7 : IN UNSIGNED (size-1 downto 0);

        MinOut:out  UNSIGNED (size-1 downto 0)
);     
END Entity;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------


ARCHITECTURE compare OF bitmin IS

type a_uns is array (0 to 7) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal a_unss:a_uns;
signal MinOut_tmp : UNSIGNED (size-1 downto 0) := 0;
signal done_flag: STD_LOGIC := '0';


begin
        a_unss(0)<=(A0);
        a_unss(1)<=(A1);
        a_unss(2)<=(A2);
        a_unss(3)<=(A3);
        a_unss(4)<=(A4);
        a_unss(5)<=(A5);
        a_unss(6)<=(A6);
        a_unss(7)<=(A7);

process(a_unss) begin
    done_flag <= '0';

    for i in 0 to 7 loop
        if (a_unss(i) < MinOut_tmp) then
            MinOut_tmp<=a_unss(i);
        end if;
    end loop;

    done_flag <= '1';
end process;
END compare;


process(done_flag) begin
    if (done_flag == '1') then
        MinOut <= MinOut_tmp;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: i know that.I watn to make i-1 when the i=7
(a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1))and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1))and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i-1)) then
   MinOut<=a_unss(i);

Comment: You can change the loop condition to be:
```vhdl
for i in 0 to 6 loop
```

Comment: Also note that the condition logic is not correct. It's checking different ```(a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1))
```
at the same time which is pointless. I know you are trying to check:
`(a_unss(0)<a_unss(1)) and (a_unss(1)<a_unss(2)) and (a_unss(2)<a_unss(3))` ... etc. but what you have wrote is not achieving this.

Comment: how can i archieve this?

Comment: i tried for i in 0 to 6 loop but it works unlti port A(7)

Comment: When you used: `(a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and (a_unss(i)<a_unss(i+1)) and ...`; what actually happens when `i = 0` is:
`(a_unss(0)<a_unss(1)) and (a_unss(0)<a_unss(1)) and (a_unss(0)<a_unss(1)) ...` 
and when `i = 1`:
`(a_unss(1)<a_unss(2)) and (a_unss(1)<a_unss(2)) and (a_unss(1)<a_unss(2)) ...` 
and so on. You are not looping correctly.
In the solution I proposed, you start with an assumed minimum and at each iteration, you check a single index of `a_unss`. If at that index `a_unss` is less than the assumed minimum, then the assumed minimum will be updated.

Comment: I added a valid flag `done_flag` that indicated that you have looped finished looping all the addresses and the result is ready to be set.